# Проблема с AdWords

Tags: android, google-adsense, google-adwords

Возникла проблема, в аккаунте adsense выбирал как валюту оплаты доллар, теперь России нет в списке, прочитал в других местах что теперь нужно создавать новый аккаунт. Возможно ли это как то исправить, или можно ли другую страну выбрать (не Россию). Деньги то терять уже не хочется. Буду рад помощи!

Comment: Обратитесь в саппорт, я думаю это лучше чем создавать новый аккаунт.

Comment: Данный вопрос следует закрыть, потому что он не имеет отношения к программированию или системному администрированию